# backgroundWorker1 no me funciona para cargar un datagridview en segundo plano

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentanto cargar un datagrid usando backgroundWorker1 pero no hace nada, ni error manda.
Mi idea es ir cargando el datagridview cada cierto tiempo sin interrumpir al usuario o que la pantalla se quede detenida un tiempo en lo que se vuelve a cargar.
Aqui cargo mi datable en el metodo LoadRequest() del DoWork y en el RunWorkerCompleted le paso los datos del e.result a mi datagrid pero no muestra nada, cabe mencionar que mi metodo LoadRequest() retorna un datatable con aproxomadamente 10 rows;

```html
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Result = LoadRequest();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridPenCoti.DataSource = e.Result;
        }
```

Este es mi metodo para retornar el datatable

```html
public static DataTable LoadRequest()
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                
                SqlConnection ConnMRO = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand CommMRO = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ID= 'Open'",ConnMRO);
                
                SqlDataAdapter adapterdata = new SqlDataAdapter(CommMRO);
                adapterdata.Fill(data);
                ConnMRO.Open();
                if( data.Rows.Count >0)
                {
                    
                    return data;
                }
                else
                {
                    return data;
                }
                ConnMRO.Close();
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return data;
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo en el código que publicaste es que no tiene la cadena de conexion a la base de datos.

La falta de una cadena de conexión, produce una exception `InvalidOperationException` y no lo notas porque en el bloque `catch` la ignoras completamente al devolver el `DataTable`.

El código debería funcionar agregando la cadena de conexión como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SqlConnection ConnMRO = new SqlConnection("Server=nombre del servidor;Database=nombre de la base de datos;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

Puedes ver otro ejemplo de cadena de conexión en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#examples).

#### Recomendaciones

- No es buena idea ignorar las excepciones. Ver [uso de excepciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/using-exceptions)
- Considera utilizar [instrucciones using](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) para garantizar el uso correcto de objetos [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0#remarks) como la conexión `SqlConnection`.
- El método `LoadRequest()` puede simplificarse eliminando la condicional `if( data.Rows.Count >0)` porque siempre devuelve el `DataTable` sin importar si la consulta tiene resultados o no.
- En general, la instrucción `ConnMRO.Open();` debería ir antes de interactuar con la base de datos, aunque en este caso no es necesario porque el `DataAdapter` se encarga de abrirla y por esta razón es innecesaria.

A continuación un ejemplo del método `LoadRequest` simplificado y utilizando `using statement`

```
public static DataTable LoadRequest()
{
    //Crea una instancia del DataTable en este punto
    //porque el método lo devuelve sin importar lo que ocurra.
    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    using (var ConnMRO = new SqlConnection("Server=nombre del servidor;Database=nombre de la base de datos;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapterdata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT...", ConnMRO))
    {
        try
        {
            adapterdata.Fill(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //No es recomendable ignorarlas 
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: gracias por lo de la cadena de conexion, si la tengo solo para fines de la pregunta no la puse. Y referente al backgroundWorker1 tienes alguna solicion?

Comment: En las pruebas que hice, el background worker funcionó como se espera. Sugiero que le quites el try...catch solo para probar si ocurre alguna excepción que no estés viendo.

Comment: la idea de usar if( data.Rows.Count ) es porque la primera vez lanzo la applicacion me carga todos los datos del query y tengo un timer para que cada 5 min me vuelva a cargar los datos, en caso de que haya registros nuevo en el else realizo la comparacion y si ya estan en el datagrid ya no los agrego, solo agrego los ultimos reigstros realizado o nuevos pero esto hace que mi formulario se quede congelado cada 5 min en lo que carga es por eso que quiero usar background worker

Comment: donde le indicas para que se ejecute el background worker porque ya lo tengo lo mas parecido a tu ejemplo y no hace nada, nunca carga los datos al datagrid y el metodo public static DataTable LoadRequest() no se ejecuta @Pablo Gutiérrez

Comment: Pero entonces publica el código el real porque mi respuesta está basada en el código que publicaste y eso que me comentas no está en el código. También en mi respuesta se asume que en algún punto de tu programa tienes la instrucción `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` sin eso el `backgroundWorker1` no hace nada.